# Python special characters encoding problems in PATH

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, character-encoding, kivy

Given this simple code, I receive faulty paths if the userfolder contains any special characters. For example the returned path is expected to be "C:\Users\Aoë\", but the ë is instead shown as a ‰ or a \u2030 depending on what is done with encoding. This then messes up the rest of my code because of attempts to write to nonexistent paths.

I ran into this problem trying to run kivy, but it seems to be happening globally.

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
print(home)
```

I've spent quite some time, but haven't been able to reach a solution. This is with the latest python, x64 on windows with eclipse. No matter what I do, I cannot get python to handle special characters properly.

Comment: Works with Python 3.6 on OSX.  Since you are on Windows there can be issues with the display encoding of the console window and some IDEs.  I find it is usually successful with  IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'r' tag at the beginning, it ignores the special characters:

```
home = r'%s'%str(Path.home())
```